# Is a system depending on HTTP get/post parameter order reliable?

Tags: http, post, get

I am trying to implement a system which depends on the HTTP get/post parameter order.

I want the system provide a remote function call mechanism, for example: 
Suppose there is a function `foo(int, int)`, it can be called remotely by HTTP get `http://ip:port/method=foo&paramType=int&param=1&paramType=int&param=2` or HTTP post with post data as `method=foo&paramType=int&param=1&paramType=int&param=2`, which acts as call `foo(1,2)` locally.

As you see, it depends on parameter order extremely. If parameter order goes wrong, `foo(2,1)` will be called unexpected.

But I am not sure is it reliable, since I think W3 did not make a spec for the parameter order(tell me if I'm wrong).

I am not sure the parameter order will be as expected at three points:

1. Will the client(such as a browser or jmeter) post the parameter in
   order as you see?
2. Will the order be preserved during transmission?
3. Will the web contain(such as tomcat) or the web framework(such as django)
   preserve the parameter order?

I did a few tests, found chrome, firefox and jmeter will send get/post parameter as expected and tomcat preserved the parameter order, but it's a hard work to find negetive cases and I am not sure there is no such cases. So I can't be sure is the system I am trying to implement is reliable.

Does anyone have any experiences for such problem? All suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Everything I've encountered keeps the order of multiple values for the same key, even if it disturbs the order of different keys.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot enforce parameter order in either a URL query string or `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` post.  Although W3C defines HTML to transmit form values in the order they appear in the HTML, server-side scripts are free to access parameters by name in any order, and having multiple parameters with the same name is a recipe for disaster.  You need to rename your parameters to make them unique and order-independant, eg:

```
method=foo&param1Type=int&param1=1&param2Type=int&param2=2
```

This way, `foo()` can read its 2 `paramX` parameters regardless of their ordering.  For instance, this would also be perfectly valid and still be functional:

```
param2=2&param1=1&param1Type=int&param2Type=int&method=foo
```

Personally, I would suggest you eliminate the `paramType` parameters:

```
method=foo&param1=1&param2=2
```

Your API spec dictates the data types of the parameters.  If a client sends a non-integer value to `foo()`, return an HTTP error, like `400 Bad Request`.  Always validate input before using it.

Comment: Do you have a link to the W3C spec?

Answer (score 0):

If the order matters I would design it in a way like @TGH said where the parameters are part of the path like `http://someServer/param1/param2`. This enforces ordering and wont allow requests to be made any other way. If you design it using query parameters expecting the browser to maintain the order, that opens up the possibility for a security hole for someone to take advantage of.